# How do I set a UInt32 to its maximum value

Tags: ios, objective-c, uint32

1. What is the maximum value for a UInt32?
2. Is there a way I can use the sizeof operator to get the maximum value (as it is unsigned)? So I don't end up with #defines or magic numbers in my code.

Comment: Wouldn't that be `2^32 - 1`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSNotFound

Comment: Damn SO, you used to be so friendly. This is a valid question, why all the down votes? Haters got to hate, I wish they would do it somewhere else though.

Comment: (uint32_t)0-1  ;-)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

There's a macro `UINT32_MAX` defined in `stdint.h` which you can use

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t max = UINT32_MAX;
```

---

#### More about the relevant header `<stdint.h>`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/basedefs/stdint.h.html

Comment: You have my up vote already, but it may be helpful for future users if you list a few more of these macros like MAXFLOAT and similar.

Comment: @0x7fffffff  You should take a look into <stdint.h>. There are virtually a few dozens of macros which define min, max for all signed and unsigned integer types and a few other macros. These are defined in the [ISO/IEC 988:1999 specification](http://www.iso.org/iso/home/store/catalogue_ics/catalogue_detail_ics.htm?csnumber=57853).

Answer (score 19):

The maximum value for UInt32 is `0xFFFFFFFF` (or 4294967295 in decimal).

`sizeof(UInt32)` would not return the maximum value; it would return 4, the size in bytes of a 32 bit unsigned integer.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was thinking maybe you could do some simple arithmetic on it (sizeof(UInt32) * 8) ^ 2. Be a bit of overkill, I was a bit sleepy when I asked.

Answer (score 4):

The portable way:

```
std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()
```

Comment: why is this more portable?

Comment: More portable in comparison with some hardcoded values. Maybe uint32_t is not a great example. If you take std::numeric_limits<int32_t> for example, you do not have to make assumption on how signed numbers are coded on the machine. If you take  std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>, you are not making any assumption about the size of an int which may not alway be 32 bit depending on the hardware that is targeted. It is also a bit more flexible than the macros. If you need to change the type, through a typedef for instance, you do not have to update all the UINT32_MAX like macros in your code.

Comment: This answer is C++ code, but the question is about Objective C on iOS.

Answer (score 4):

Just set the max using standard hexadecimal notation and then check it against whatever you need.  32-bits is 8 hexadecimals bytes, so it'd be like this:

```
let myMax: UInt32 = 0xFFFFFFFF

if myOtherNumber > myMax {
    // resolve problem
}
```

Answer (score 2):

4_294_967_295 is the maximal value or in hexadecimal 0xFFFFFFFF.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for any unsigned in C or C++ is:

```
anUnsigned = -1;
```

This is useful since it works for them all, so if you change from `unsigned int` to `unsigned long` you don't need to go through your code. You will also see this used in a lot of bit fiddling code:

```
anUnsigned |= -(aBoolOrConditionThatWhenTrueCausesAnUnsignedToBeSetToAll1s)
anUnsigned |= -(!aValueThatWhenZeroCausesAnUnsignedToBeSetToAll1s)
anUnsigned |= -(!!aValueThatWhenNonZeroCausesAnUnsignedToBeSetToAll1s)
```

The downside is that it looks odd, assigning a negative number to an unsigned!

Comment: sometimes doing it this way causes compiler warnings or static analysis warnings, pity because it works fine! :)

Comment: To avoid a compiler warning and make it clear to other readers that you know what you're doing, cast the value to the correct type, e.g. `anUnsigned = (uint32_t)-1;` .